# ASP.NET Core AddAuthorization method is missing from ConfigureServices only on IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, https

I am developing an app on ASP.NET Core with usage of ASP.NET Authentication and Authorization middlewares. When launching it from Visual Studio it works fine as well as launching it from Docker Compose (was created via "Enable Docker support..." menu in VS).
However deploying my app to Windows Server with IIS installed returns an error

```
Application startup exception
  System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
     at TravelReporting.WebUI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\sanch\MainRepo\TravelReporting.WebUI\Startup.cs:line 119
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here's my Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;
using TravelReporting.Application.Infrastructure.AutoMapper;
using TravelReporting.Application.Interfaces;
using TravelReporting.Application.Services;
using TravelReporting.Infrastructure.Logging;
using TravelReporting.Persistence;
using TravelReporting.Persistence.Identity;
using TravelReporting.Persistence.Repositories;
using TravelReporting.Persistence.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace TravelReporting.WebUI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureProductionServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionStringForIdentity = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringForIdentity, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TravelReporting.Persistence")));

            var connectionStringForContext = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContextConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<TravelReportingDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringForContext, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TravelReporting.Persistence")));
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            ConfigureProductionServices(services);

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
            {
                // SingIn settings.
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

                // User settings.
                opt.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var viewAssembly = typeof(RazorViewRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var fileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(viewAssembly);
            services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => {
                options.FileProviders.Clear();
                options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider);
            });
            services.AddScoped<IRazorViewRenderer, RazorViewRenderer>();

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

            //services.AddScoped<NumberService, NumberService>();
            //services.AddScoped<DateService, DateService>();
            //services.AddScoped<EstimateReportService, EstimateReportService>();
            //services.AddScoped<ProgramReportService, ProgramReportService>();
            //services.AddScoped<DelegationReportService, DelegationReportService>();
            //services.AddScoped<OrderReportService, OrderReportService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<,>), typeof(BaseService<,>));

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppLogger<>), typeof(LoggerAdapter<>));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with this issue?

**What I tried already:**

1. Manually installing certificate on Server VM
2. Removing `AddAuthorization()` and `UseAuthorization()` methods completely
3. `UseIISIntegration()` already added in HostBuilder
4. Added certificate thumbprint into Azure Release Pipeline for IIS Deployment
5. Installed Core 3.1 runtime as @jdweng proposed
6. Performed steps from link provided by @jdweng

Comment: Need to download runtime version of Core (right column).  Here is link to Core 3.1. You may need different version.

Comment: @jdweng no luck with this one, also forgot to mention - already installed dotnet hosting bundle

Comment: See second paragraph : https://discountasp.net/asp.net-hosting/asp.net-core/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIi9iG5Y6z8AIVSuWzCh0PegDlEAAYASAAEgLyt_D_BwE

Comment: @jdweng still stumbled upon same error. thanks for you suggestions anyway, will update my quesion with these steps.

Comment: When running in the `Production` environment, `ConfigureProductionServices` gets called, but `ConfigureServices` does _not_.

Comment: Commend out following line : services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);